# How do you pronounce Linux?

Tags: linux

Is there a proper pronunciation for the word Linux?

Could someone write the phonetics for pronouncing "Linux", and also the somewhat notorious variant "Lye-nix"?

I *think* this is right...

- **Lɪnɪx, NOT Lɚnɪx**.

...or perhaps...

- **Lɪnʌx, NOT Lɚnʌx***

Can someone confirm the correct phonetics? (**[Listen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IfHm6R5le0) to Linus** on the matter).

Answer (score 21):

[Linus Torvalds](http://www.jx90.com/linux.html) take on the matter.

*Edit: Links seems to be down. Here is the almost complete content:*

> "Hello this is Linus Torvalds and I pronounce Linux as Linux."

([alternative Source](http://www.paul.sladen.org/pronunciation/))

Answer (score 4):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IfHm6R5le0

Answer (score 2):

Crikey! Do you all say "..ix"? I've always pronounced the "u" as a "u"...

Comment: I give you +1 for just admitting that you've mispronounced it, and now you know =D.

Comment: I dunno - Linus Torvalds sounds like he says it my way - though maybe that's because of how I interpret a Finnish accent through British ears...

Comment: My bad teedyay - I completely misread your post - you were referring to the ending "...ix", I was talking about the starting "li..." =)

In which case - I think your pronunciation must have been perfectly fine.

Comment: I guess the people who say -ix, also pronounce Linus as line-is, right? :)

Comment: liNIX, as in uNIX. Sheesh

Answer (score 2):

There is a you-tube video where Linus Torvalds, creator of Linux, explains how the word should be pronounced.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IfHm6R5le0

some more referrance:
http://safalra.com/science/linguistics/linux-pronunciation/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux

gives you audio files.

Answer (score 1):

As for i know I used to pronounce LINUX. L I N U X.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I always say unix - but that doesn't endear me to the devs...

Comment: Linux is not unix :-P

Comment: ohhh i know.... still its funny to me...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you should pronounce it "*lee-nooks*"

Comment: lol thats very funny...

Comment: That is, phonetically, how they say it in Finnish. And since Linus is from Finland, well, there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

in Italy: "leenooks" (in phonetic symbols: l'inucs)

Answer (score 1):

Lye nucks

I know people who say lih nucks, but its just sounds wrong to me

Comment: +1 me too. I started pronouncing it this way and it was burned into my brain before I learned that it was "wrong".  If saying lye-nucks is wrong, I don't want to be right!

Comment: Just remember, folks LINE-X is a brand of Pickup truck bed liners, not operating systems ;-)

Answer (score 1):

2 out of 10 people will pronounce common everyday words differently - what makes you think and hope there will ever be a consencus on how to p-ronounce "Linux" ?

Apart from that ... like Linus with an x. (I don't think I can post audio with these answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Li-nix".

Answer (score 0):

Linux *pron*:Lyn-ux

Answer (score 0):

I normally go with "ooboon2"

Answer (score 0):

That's ***GNU*** Linux to you. Just ask Richard M. Stallman.